# Ruby MongoDB drop GridFS collection

Tags: ruby, mongodb

How do I drop a Grid object with the Ruby Mongo Driver?
I do `drop` from the shell, because it treats GridFS as collections, but how do I do it with Ruby?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to remove a single file or the entire GridFS collections? the grid_file_system supports deleting by filename. Otherwise you can manually drop the collections (I think fs.files and fs.chunks by default)

Comment: I want to remove the entire GridFS collections by calling a method like `remove` on the Ruby `Grid` object, but I guess that's not possible. Looks like I'll have to create Collection objects for each of the collections that make up the GridFS and call `remove` on both of them.

Answer (score 1):

Grids it's just to collections: files and chunks. So just drop these two collections.

I am not familiar with ruby but mb [this link](http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/1.2.1/Mongo/Collection.html#remove-instance_method) will be useful for you.